# how to do the conversion to meet the below requirements ( json object to json array ) or directly from xml to json array?

Tags: json

after converting the below XML to json, i get the following result.

XML:

```
<biometrics>
    <type>FMR</type>
    <positionHint>left</positionHint>
    <biometricSample>wrwerwerwerw</biometricSample>
</biometrics>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "biometrics":
    {
      "type" : "FMR",
      "positionHint":"left",
      "biometricSample":"wrwerwerwerw"
    }
}
```

Though the above converted json is valid.
The system is expecting the json to be of the below format( json array).

```
{
  "biometrics": 
  [ 
    {
       "type" : "FMR",
       "positionHint":"left",
       "biometricSample":"wrwerwerwerw"
    }
  ]
}
```

from the above json its clear that the system expecting square brackets.
though there is a single object. the system expects it in the form of json array.

tried converting from jsonobject to json array or XML to json array or string to json array...

But could get the required json with square brackets as per the above json.

Ps requesting ur assistance on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just say `json.biometrics = [json.biometrics];`.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Define your data structure in terms of the programming language you are using. 
Step two: Convert XML into that data structure. 
Step three: Convert that data structure into JSON.

Obviously the data structure wants an *array*. XML doesn't really have arrays, just the same kind of element 0, 1 or more times so you can't look at the XML and see it contains an array, but you know that you need an array. Your code parsing the XML would expect 0, 1 or more XML elements  and put them all into one array.

Answer (score 0):

It really does not makes sense what you are expecting because json will contain an array if you have multiple sub-nodes mean many nodes under the node. Even though you can try like this

create a class

```
public class TestBio {
    List<Biometrics> biometrics = new ArrayList<Biometrics>();
    public TestBio(Biometrics biometric){
        biometrics.add(biometric);
    }
}
```

One more class

```
public class Biometrics {
    private String type;
    private String positionHint;
    private String biometricSample;
    public Biometrics(){}
    //getters setters toString etc
 }
```

Then in some main method

```
String str ="{\n" +
        "\"biometrics\":{\n" +
        "\"type\" : \"FMR\",\n" +
        "\"positionHint\":\"left\",\n" +
        "\"biometricSample\":\"wrwerwerwerw\"\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "}";
JsonObject o = new JsonParser().parse(str).getAsJsonObject();
String bio = o.get("biometrics").toString();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Biometrics biometrics = gson.fromJson (bio, Biometrics.class);
TestBio t =new TestBio(biometrics);
String gsonArray = gson.toJson(t);
System.out.println(gsonArray);
```

Again saying you this is not the ideal approach because the json generated is the correct one if you xml nodes are in that pattern